# sql - find users with at least 1 order AND have conditions for each order. Use count?

Tags: mysql, join

I am running a MySQL database in rails 2.3. my model associations that I am interacting with in this query are as follows:

models: users and orders

users have 1 email

users have many orders

orders have a created at date

**I want to make a list of emails from all users who have at least one order with the latest order being at least 3 months old** (so, lets say today is feb 24th 2012, the last order was placed on nov 24th 2011 or earlier)

I know how to grab orders created on or before nov 24th with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE created_at <= "2011-11-24 00:00:00.000000 -08:00"
```

I don't know how to find users with at least 1 order AND have those conditions for each order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the tables' definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT users.email
FROM users
  JOIN
    ( SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING MAX(created_at) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
    ) AS oo
    ON oo.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY oo.created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another answer.  I have just noticed you are using rails 2.3

In that case, maybe:

```
User.all.orders(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", Time.now - 3.months])
```

Put the order by as a default scope in your Order model, e.g.

```
default_scope :order_by => 'created_at'
```

Syntax might need a little work as I mostly use Rails 3 with the AREL syntax

Comment: While this probably will work, I want to keep the queries strictly to SQL. I also don't want to change the models when its not essential to.

Comment: That's fine.  I would still recommend doing it in rails though.  Using lots of sql in a rails application is a major code smell.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.email
FROM orders, users
WHERE orders.user_id = users.id
AND orders.created_at < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
ORDER BY orders.created_at DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, this did what I was trying to accomplish. I added a DISTINCT in the beginning so the emails weren't repeated.

Comment: Actually, does this answer make sure ALL orders are at least 3 months old? I see emails form clients who i am sure have ordered recently.

Comment: This doesn't look correct. The `>` means that orders during the last 3 months will be selected, not older than.